# How to use select * from in codeigniter 3?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter, even I'm a newbie. What if a line of native code like this is implemented in codeigneter, how to display it? I'm not familiar with model or view controllers. usually i work only with native

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <select class="custom-select" onchange='changeValue(this.value)' required>
        <option>Select Account</option>
        <?php 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from nflx_acc");  
        $jsArray = "var accData = new Array();\n";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
        echo '<option value="' . $row['nflxorder'] . '">No.' . $row['id'] . '</option>';  
        $jsArray .= "accData['" . $row['nflxorder'] . "'] = {order_mail:'" . addslashes($row['nflxorder']) . "',order_code:'".addslashes($row['nflxcode'])."',category:'".addslashes($row['type'])."'};\n";

        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<input id="order_mail">
<input id="order_code">
<input id="category">

<script> 
    <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
    function changeValue(id){
        document.getElementById('order_mail').value = accData[id].order_mail;
        document.getElementById('order_code').value = accData[id].order_code;
        document.getElementById('category').innerHTML = accData[id].category;
    };
</script>
```

Its function displays data from database "nflx_acc" in the form of select options,
when select is selected display data to text field from row ['nflxorder'],['nflxcode'],['type']

Comment: So why do you use a framework if you want to use a native php? Also, putting html and sql in one file is a bad idea. I'd suggest you to spend some time reading CodeIgniter docs and learn basics

Comment: Because currently I am required with codeigniter framework

Comment: @MaruliDavin Well if you are "required" to work with CodeIgniter that would lead one to thinking that you are "required" to read the Docs etc on it.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter has [Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) class which you can use it to run MySQL queries.

```
$query = get_instance()->db->get('nflx_acc');
if($query -> num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($query -> result_array() as $row)
    {
        // do your work
    }
}
else echo "No rows to return";
```

Comment: Thanks this works but when I select an option it doesn't change anything, only changes if the last row is selected

Comment: There might be a problem somewhere in your `<select>`'s `<option>` part. Please re-check.